# How to find rocks worth tumbling?

Tags: rocks, california

My son recently got a [rock tumbler](http://geology.com/rock-tumbler/) and I was wondering if anybody knows of any resources that would show pictures of the different types of rocks as they would be found on the ground. I live in Chino Hills CA and we have many trails. I wanted to be able to tell the difference between something worth tumbling and something that isn't.

Comment: I edited your answer and while looking up the link I found this: http://geology.com/rock-tumbler/tumbling-rough.shtml

Answer (score 3):

Any stone quartz rich and smooth not porous (no visible holes) like agates, quartzite or cherts are you best bet for getting a nice tumbled stone.

A great book is:

Gems and Minerals of America: A Guide to Rock Collecting (1st Edition)
by Jay Ellis Ransom
Hardcover, 705 Pages, Published 1975

ISBN-10: 0-06-013512-3        / 0060135123
ISBN-13: 978-0-06-013512-6 / 9780060135126

Your local library might have a copy of it.
See to find on sale on Internet also: used ~$5.00

http://www.gettextbooks.com/isbn/9780060135126

BTW, tumbling stones and rock collecting led me to a career as a geologist.